# Present spotify playlists as xml

Tags: spotify

I was wondering if it's possible to present spotify playlists as xml without using services like libspotify.

They have to functions "lookup" and "search" for web developers but they don't seem to present data as xml for playlists.

Is there in some way possible to present this?

Thankful for some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no, this isn't possible.